# How to store/process multiple tables's data using MySql and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, select, multiple-tables

I have 5 different MySql tables viz:

> u_t (uid, pwd, field1, field2)
>
> t_1 (tid_1, ut_uid, field_1, field_2, points)
>
> t_2 (tid_2, ut_uid, field_1, field_2, points)
>
> t_3 (tid_3, ut_uid, field_1, field_2, points)
>
> t_4 (tid_4, ut_uid, field_1, field_2, points)
>
> PS: uid=pk , tid_1,2,3,4=pk, ut_uid=fk

All the above tables are having some information based on some unique features.

Now i want to get the sum of points from each table for every user for storing and displaying purpose, using PHP.

Comment: [whathaveyoutried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Query by juergen d gives what you want. Does not it?
Have you got connection with mysql database in php? Do you also need PHP statements to fetch this result? Do you also need PHP statements to display the fetched results in a table? Answer these questions and your problem is solved.

Answer (score 3):

try

```
select u_t.uid, 
       sum(t_1.points+t_2.points+t_3.points+t_4.points+t_5.points) as total_p
from u_t
left outer join t_1 on t_1.ut_uid = u_t.uid
left outer join t_2 on t_2.ut_uid = u_t.uid
left outer join t_3 on t_3.ut_uid = u_t.uid
left outer join t_4 on t_4.ut_uid = u_t.uid
group by u_t.uid
```

Answer (score 0):

An uglier version of this:

```
SELECT ut.uid, sum(t1.pts + t2.pts + t3.pts + t4.pts) total
FROM u_t ut
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT ut_uid, sum(points) pts
  FROM t_1
  GROUP BY ut_uid
) t1
  on ut.uid = t1.ut_uid
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT ut_uid, sum(points) pts
  FROM t_2
  GROUP BY ut_uid
) t2
  on ut.uid = t2.ut_uid
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT ut_uid, sum(points) pts
  FROM t_3
  GROUP BY ut_uid
) t3
  on ut.uid = t3.ut_uid
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT ut_uid, sum(points) pts
  FROM t_4
  GROUP BY ut_uid
) t4
  on ut.uid = t4.ut_uid
GROUP BY ut.uid
```